# Coordinates are nil when selecting annotation on map Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm changing one part of my app from displaying some shops in a `UITableview` to display them on a `MKMapView` and they display  fine but I'm getting nil coordinate values when I select the annotations on the map. In `didAdd` I print them and they are fine, and in fact the annotation is displayed on map.
It has been a while since I last used `MapKit` and I can't spot if the problem is in the custom annotation class or somewhere else. Can you spot where I'm misusing it?
As always many thanks for you time and help.
This is the annotation class:

```
class ShopAnnotation: NSObject , MKAnnotation {

    var title: String?
    var coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var image: UIImage?
    var shopName: String?
    var shopLogoUrl: String?

    init(title: String, iconImage: UIImage, coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D, shopName: String, shopLogoUrl: String) {


        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.shopName = shopName
        self.shopLogoUrl = shopLogoUrl
        self.image = iconImage

    }
}
```

than I have a an array that I take values from :

```
var availableShopsArray:[(name:String, logoUrl:String, homeLat: String, homeLong: String)] = []
```

I than loop through it and place an annotation on the map:

```
func displayShops() {
        mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)

        for shop in availableShopsArray {
            let coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(shop.homeLat)!, longitude: Double(shop.homeLong)!)
            let title = "Route Mid"
            let image = UIImage(named: title)!
            let shopAnn: ShopAnnotation = ShopAnnotation(title: title, iconImage: image, coordinate: coordinates, shopName: shop.name, shopLogoUrl: shop.logoUrl)
            mapView.addAnnotation(shopAnn)
        }
//        self.availableShopsTableview.reloadData()
    }
```

when I select one I should take the values from it, but coordinate is nil :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        guard let selectedShop = view.annotation as? ShopAnnotation else {return}
        self.shopLogoUrl = selectedShop.shopLogoUrl!
        self.selectedShopCoordinates.latitude = selectedShop.coordinate.latitude
        self.selectedShopCoordinates.longitude = selectedShop.coordinate.longitude
        self.selectedShopName = selectedShop.shopName

//        calculateBookingType()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "bookingToCartSegue", sender: self)
    }
```

and this is `viewForAnnotation` :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? { // rajish version
        let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "")

        if annotation is MKUserLocation{
            return nil
        } else {
            print("Annotation.coordinates are: \(String(describing: annotation.coordinate))")
//            print("annotation title is: \(String(describing: annotation.title!))")
            annotationView.image = UIImage(named:(annotationView.annotation?.title)! ?? "")

            annotationView.canShowCallout = true
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.27, y: 0.27) // alert annotation's icons size
            annotationView.transform = transform
            // makin allerts draggable
            annotationView.isDraggable = false
            return annotationView
        }
    }
```

Comment: make sure it's not  nil originally from your model

Comment: I added print("displayShops() coordinates are: \(coordinates)")in displaySops() and it prints them fine. Where could they get lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly enough I was assigning latitude and longitude separately to `selectedShopCoordinates` from `selectedShop.coordinate`and on that it would find nil.
I now assign them as coordinates as `selectedShopCoordinates = selectedShop.coordinate` and is not crashing anymore.

Why would it find nil on single coordinates degrees is still a mystery. 
Any idea on why would be very much appreciated.
Hope this will help others struggling with it.
Cheers